# Reset the default program to none

Tags: xfce

When I open a file it asked for a program and I clicked "Application Finder" which is wrong. Now I want to reset the default program to none.

If anyone is curious it is xampp's "manager-linux-x64.run" and by default it ask for an application to use to open it.